# gridcomplete function always running?

Tags: javascript, grails, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid with grails and need to select some objects. This works for one given object. My problem is that sometimes, calling function has no id. So there is nothing to do after grid completion. And I'm not able to do that even after trying if (false)... In all case, grid.jqgrid("setSelection... is executed and I get the message

java.lang.NullPointerException
Cannot get property 'id' on null object

which is true. But why is this line executed ???

```
gridComplete: function() {
  if (false) {
     grid.jqGrid("setSelection",'${cableFocus.id}',true);
  }
```

return;

I have a second question : How can I use gridComplete to select several rows instead of one ?

Thanks very much for any help,

Olivier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with gridComplete or your if statement (which is javascript). As you are getting a java error i'm guessing ${cableFocus.id} is placeholder (which will always get exectuted)

So the javascript is not running but your java code is still attempting to run and throwing the error